# Google Spreadsheet Script working with strings

Tags: string, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a question about how to work with 'string' type in Google Script?

I have a column with sites in different formats, e.g.
http://testsite.com/, http://www.sitetest.net/, dot.anothersite.com, http://anysite.net/index.html
and so on.

So I want to automatically format these records to one template: sitename.domain (for example http://testsite.com/ = testsite.com || http://www.sitetest.net/ = sitetest.net)

I get this info by this script:

```
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var sheetName = sheet.getName();
  var restrictSheet = "Summary";
  if (sheetName != restrictSheet){ // I don't need to modify first sheet from my spreadsheet
    var sheetRange = sheet.getActiveRange();
    var sData = sheet.getRange("A3:A"); // column with sites
    var TextArray = sData.getValues();
  }else Browser.msgBox("wrong sheet");
}
```

And I don't know how to work with strings in google script. In C++, for example, I could use string functions like String.Find() or String.Mid(). But I can't see equal functions in Google Scripts

Answer (score 36):

Well... I've found the answer on my own question :D

Google Script uses String class from JavaScript
So functions and methods from JS works also in Google Scripts..

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_string.asp

May be it will help somebody.

Answer (score 13):

May be a little late..

but it would be good to know that many common string object methods **do not** work in Google App Script.
For e.g. **.endsWith**, **.includes** etc.

check this stackoverflow [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39669460/2637998).

here are a few tests to verify

```
function stringEndsWithTest(){
  var a = "abc@example.com";
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert('endsWith method on a string in google app script '+ a.endsWith('.com')); 
}

function stringIncludesTest(){
  var a = "abc@example.com";
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert('includes method on a string in google app script '+ a.includes('.com')); 
}
```

I was getting this error at the time of writing this answer

> TypeError: Cannot find function includes in object abc@example.
>   (line 19, file "main")

as an alternative of above methods what helped me was 'indexOf' method

```
function stringIndexOfTest(){
  var a = "abc@example.com";
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert('indexOf method on a string in google app script '+ a.indexOf('.com')); 
}
```

I hope it might help someone.

Comment: The thing is you have to convert the variable 'a' into a string using `b = a.toString();`. Then you can use String class methods.

Comment: This helped alot, GAS does not provide the same String class methods as js in the wild.