# TypeError: Cannot find function includes in object

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have very little experience using Google Script but I was attempting to use it to search through one column of a spreadsheet and find all instances of the string "Film Dub" (knowing that there can be only one per cell).

Below is my code:

```
    function filmDub() {
      var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
      var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
      for (var i = 1; i < 100; i++) {
        var s = data[i][2].toString();
        if (s.includes('Film Dub')) {
          data[5][13]++;
        }
      }
    }
```

However I keep receiving the error

> `TypeError: Cannot find function includes in object Let's Make A Date, Film Dub, Three Headed Broadway Star, Film TV Theater Styles, Greatest Hits, World's Worst. (line 6, file "Code")`

"*Let's Make A Date, Film Dub, Three Headed Broadway Star, Film TV Theater Styles, Greatest Hits, World's Worst*" is the correct content of `data[i][2]` so it is getting correct information from the spreadsheet. I have used the debugger in Google Script Editor to verify that `s` is a string (this was one of the solutions to similar questions here on Stack Overflow) but that didn't fix my problem. What else could be wrong with it?

Comment: What does `typeof s` return?

Comment: `typeof s` returns `string`

Answer (score 15):

You should use indexOf with a string to check for the existence of a text block.

```
function filmDub() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  for (var i = 1; i < 100; i++) {
    var s = data[i][2].toString();
    if (s.indexOf('Film Dub') !== -1) {
      data[5][13]++;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: When I do that I get the following error: `TypeError: Cannot read property "2" from undefined. (line 5, file "Code")`

Comment: i was facing this issue with endsWith method in app script but surprisingly 'indexOf' method works in my case too.

Answer (score 4):

**you just need to enable v8 engine of apps script.**

1. click on Run in menu bar.
2. click on Enable Run time apps script V8 engine.

and then run.

I got same error before after enabling v8 engine it works very well.

Answer (score 1):

Upon further checking, double check how your sheet is formed. This is how I formed the sheet to make your code working.

```
         [A]                  [B]                   [C]
[1]Let's Make A Date     Film Dub Three     Headed Broadway Star
         [0]                  [1]                   [2]
```

Here is you code:

```
function filmDub() {
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
for (var i = 1; i < 10; i++) {
var s = data[i][2].toString();
//Logger.log(s);
if (s.indexOf("Film Dub")> -1) {
Logger.log("Horray");
}
}
}
```

Here is the result:
[image]

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your Sheet is running the current version of Apps Script. When you open the script editor you should see a yellow notice at the top that says "This project is running on our new Apps Script runtime powered by Chrome V8." If not, there should be an option to enable it. The includes function is new for Sheets scripting. You'll need to enable it individually for every Sheet in which you intend to use it.

Answer (score 0):

I am not an expert on Google Apps Script, but what I know it's javascript, so why not use the following JS method:

```
if(s.indexOf('Film Dub') > -1)
```

Comment: When I do that I receive the following error: `TypeError: Cannot read property "2" from undefined. (line 5, file "Code")`

Comment: When down voting, one should explain his action!! If s indeed is a string, then s.indexOf() should work. You're probably getting the error because of something else. Can you share which line is 'line 5' in your code?